# Download file in angular from java backend service

Tags: java, angular, rest, file, download

I'm trying to download a file that I send from my back end server.
The get method works well on postman, but I can't make it work from my front-end app (angular 5).

**Here's my back end:**

```
@GET
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/recupererDocument/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(value = {Response.Status.OK, Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST,
                Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,})
@ElementClass(request = Long.class, response = Response.class)
public Response recupererDocument(
    @NotNull(message = "L'id (identifiant du document) est obligatoire") @PathParam("id") final String id);



public Response recupererDocument(String id) {
File file = null;
final WebTarget target = ...;

Builder builderDoc = target.request(typeMime);

final Response reponseDocument = builderDoc.accept(typeMime).get();
    LOGGER.debug(reponseDocument.getStatus());

if (reponseDocument.getStatus() == 200) {
    file = reponseDocument.readEntity(new GenericType<File>() {
    });
}
reponseDocument.close();
return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).build();
}
```

**And my front-end:**

```
telechargerPieceJointe(id: string): void {
    this.s
        .telechargerPieceJointe(id)
        .then(pj => {
            this.downloadFile(pj);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            if (isDevMode()) {
                console.log('Erreur : ' + e);
            }
        });
}

downloadFile(data: Response) {
    const blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
}


telechargerPieceJointe(id: string): Promise<any> {
    const url = environment.rest.local.recupererDocument + '/' + id;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        Accept: 'application/pdf',
        responseType: 'blob'
    });

    return this.httpClient.get(url, {headers}).toPromise();
}
```

Right now in my front end in debug I don't enter the ".then' method but the .catch.

I've the following message :

> Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0.

But in the "network" tab in chrome dev tools the request is good (200), and I can see my object in the "response" part. I don't understand why it's not working :/.

If someone sees what I'm doing wrong it would probably save my sanity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular tries to parse your http response body as JSON (which is the default response type).
The `responseType` isn't specified in the `HttpHeaders` but in the httpOptions Object.

Specify `responseType: 'blob'` in the httpOptions you pass to `httpClient.get`.

```ts
telechargerPieceJointe(id: string): Observable<any> {
    const url = environment.rest.local.recupererDocument + '/' + id;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        Accept: 'application/pdf'
    });

    return this.httpClient.get(url, { headers, responseType: 'blob' });
}
```

Comment: It works !

I understood what the problem was but had no idea how to make it work.

Thanks !